# How to find what button was pressed last in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am working with Java JDK 14.0.2 right now on a java swing project. I am using Eclipse (if that matters). I am trying to use the action listener attached to my JButtons in order to see which button was pressed previously and then perform a different action based on what button was pressed before.

I have the following project:

TestFrame.java

```
package TestSwing;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        super();
        
        this.add(new TestPanel());
        
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

TestFrame.java is being instantiated in a different file where the main method is.

TestPanel.Java

```
package TestSwing;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    public TestPanel() {
        super();
        
        this.add(new TestButton1());
        this.add(new TestButton2());
    }

}
```

**Now the important part of the question** The two buttons:

TestButton1.java

```
package TestSwing;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class TestButton1 extends JButton {

    public TestButton1() {
        super();
        
        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (/*last button pressed before this one is TestButton2*/) {
                    System.out.println("Button 2 was pressed last");
                }
                else if (/*last button pressed before this one was itself*/) {  // It is important that this is else if
                    System.out.println("Button 1 was pressed last");
                }
                
            }
            
        });
        
        this.setText("Button 1");
    }

}
```

And here is button 2:

```
package TestSwing;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class TestButton2 extends JButton {

    public TestButton2() {
        super();
        
        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ;
                
            }
            
        });
        
        this.setText("Buttton 2");
    }

}
```

I have already tried searching for a solution for this but cannot find what I was looking for and I have no idea on how to begin to do this myself. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: replace your addActionListener with lambda expressions. this.addActionListener(e -> ...); much cleaner

Comment: Please comment back if any questions about my answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't extend JButton. There is no need and it only serves to confuse since you have your listener *internal* in the JButton class.
2. Separate the listener from the button -- get it outside of your JButton class.
3. Why not give both buttons the same action listener?
4. Within the listener add a JButton field that is assigned the ActionEvent's source reference (obtained via `e.getSource()`). This will hold the reference to the last button pressed.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LastButtonPressed  {
    private JButton lastButton = null;
    private JButton previousButton = null;
    private JTextField lastButtonsText = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField previousButtonsText = new JTextField(10);
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    
    public LastButtonPressed() {
        int sides = 8;
        JPanel buttonGridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(sides, sides));
        ActionListener listener = e -> {
            previousButton = lastButton;
            lastButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
            previousButtonsText.setText(lastButtonsText.getText());
            lastButtonsText.setText(e.getActionCommand());
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < sides * sides; i++) {
            String text = "Button " + (i + 1);
            JButton button = new JButton(text);
            button.addActionListener(listener);
            buttonGridPanel.add(button);
        }
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Previous Button:"));
        topPanel.add(previousButtonsText);
        topPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Button:"));
        topPanel.add(lastButtonsText);
        
        
        mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        mainPanel.add(buttonGridPanel);
    }
    
    public JPanel getMainPanel() {
        return mainPanel;
    }
    
    
    public JButton getLastButton() {
        return lastButton;
    }

    public JButton getPreviousButton() {
        return previousButton;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Last Button Pressed");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new LastButtonPressed().getMainPanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
        });
    }
    
}
```

- updated to add previous button information

---

## Explanation of portions the code

Variables (fields) that hold that last button pressed as well as the previous button pressed *before* the last one:

```
private JButton lastButton = null;
private JButton previousButton = null;
```

JTextFields to display the text held on these last buttons:

```
private JTextField lastButtonsText = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField previousButtonsText = new JTextField(10);
```

Main JPanel that holds the application:

```
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Create a JPanel that holds an 8x8 grid of JButtons:

```
int sides = 8;
JPanel buttonGridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(sides, sides));
```

Create an ActionListener that is added to the buttons. Inside the listener, set the previous button as well as the last button, and update the text held by the JTextFields:

```
ActionListener listener = e -> {
    previousButton = lastButton;
    lastButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
    previousButtonsText.setText(lastButtonsText.getText());
    lastButtonsText.setText(e.getActionCommand());
};
```

In a for-loop, create the 8x8 JButtons, add the ActionListener to each button and add each button to the JPanel grid:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sides * sides; i++) {
    String text = "Button " + (i + 1);
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    buttonGridPanel.add(button);
}
```

Add everything to the sub-JPanels and the main JPanel:

```
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.add(new JLabel("Previous Button:"));
topPanel.add(previousButtonsText);
topPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
topPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Button:"));
topPanel.add(lastButtonsText);


mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
mainPanel.add(buttonGridPanel);
```

Create a JFrame in a Swing thread-safe manner, create our LastButtonPressed instance and add its main JPanel to the JFrame, and finally display the JFrame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Last Button Pressed");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new LastButtonPressed().getMainPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    });
}
```